# How do I specify a candidate key and a foreign key when creating a table in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

How do I specify a candidate key and a foreign key when creating a table in Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from rics:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
(   supplier_id     numeric(10)     not null,
    supplier_name   varchar2(50)    not null,
    CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id),
    CONSTRAINT supplier_unique_name UNIQUE (supplier_name)
);

CREATE TABLE supplier_parts
(   supplier_id     numeric(10)     not null,
    part_name       varchar2(50)    not null,
    CONSTRAINT supplier_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
       REFERENCES supplier (supplier_id)  
);

CREATE TABLE silly
(   supplier_name   varchar2(50),
    CONSTRAINT supplier_name_fk FOREIGN KEY (supplier_name)
       REFERENCES supplier (supplier_name)  
);
```

In the above example, `supplier_pk` is a Primary key. `supplier_pk` and `supplier_unique_name` are candidate keys. `supplier_id_fk` and `supplier_name_fk` are Referential Integrity constraints (or Foreign keys).

Answer (score 0):

A candidate key is a key that uniquely identifies rows in a table. It can be used as the primary key of the table. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
(   supplier_id     numeric(10)     not null,
    supplier_name   varchar2(50)    not null,
    contact_name    varchar2(50),   
    CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);
```

Comment: yes, so what is the candidate key in your table, I want to specify it, but I don't know the syntax.

Comment: supplier_id - the list of fields in the parens after primary key- also you could add a unique constraint for another candidate key

Comment: @baboonWorksFine: there is no "the" candidate key, a candidate key is just that - a column (or group of columns) that is a *candidate* for being the primary key.